# Transforming quadratic forms, how is this theorem called?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

In my textbook there is the following nameless theorem:

> Let  $Q=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}X_i X_j$ with $a_{ij}=a_{ji}\in K$ be a quadratic form in $n$ variables over a field $K$ not of characteristic $2$. Then there is a linear transformation of coordinates, such that $Q$ has the form
>   $$ Q = \sum_{i=1}^r a_i X_i^2 \text{ with $a_i \neq 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, r$ } \, .$$
>   The invariant $r$ is the rank of the quadratic form $Q$.

Is this Sylvester's law of inertia?

I think it ***must*** be...

Comment: Sylvester's law of inertia applies to real/complex matrices, and states that the $a_i$ may be chosen to each be in $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: However, perhaps your theorem is an extension to arbitrary fields.

Comment: What book are you talking about????

Comment: Your transformation of Q is called "polar form of the quadratic form Q"

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure  you are talking about Hermite reduction. The construction is not the same as Sylvester; we are not making any distinction between positive and negative diagonal elements, indeed a field cannot be ordered unless it is characteristic zero.

NOTE: yes, in George Leo Watson, *Integral Quadratic Forms*, pages 17-19, he discusses a specific version of this as being Hermite's method of reduction. Earlier on page 9 he mentions a more general version under the heading "Rational diagonalization" where he does not multiply through in order to always have integer entries.

Best with induction on $n.$  Re-order so that $a_{11} \neq 0.$ 
Consider 
$$  a_{11}(x_1 + \frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}} x_2  + \frac{a_{13}}{a_{11}} x_3 + \cdots + \frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}} x_n  )^2   $$

This is
$$ a_{11} \left( x_1^2 +  2 \frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}} x_1 x_2  + 2 \frac{a_{13}}{a_{11}} x_1 x_3 + \cdots + 2 \frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}} x_1 x_n + \mbox{ OTHER}    \right)
$$
or
$$ a_{11}  x_1^2 +  2 a_{12} x_1 x_2  + 2 a_{13} x_1 x_3 + \cdots + 2 a_{1n} x_1 x_n + \mbox{ OTHER}_2 
$$

Now, subtract this off from the original $Q$ you wrote. What remains is a quadratic form in $n-1$ variables. Repeat the first step.

CAVEAT. I need to think about what happens when the only diagonal entries remaining are zero. We just make a trivial change to force the first diagonal entry to be nonzero. For example, consider the form $2xy$ in just two variables. If we take $x = u-v, \; y = u+v$ the new form is $2 u^2 - 2 v^2.$ That is, the ability to force the first diagonal coefficient to be nonzero is simply the ability for the form to represent a nonzero number, that is the form is not the zero form.

Comment: Concerning what you say in order a field be ordered, you have to add besides the characteristic zero  the condition "-1 is not a square".

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez, not actually enough. In $\mathbb Q (\sqrt{-2}),$ $-1$ is not a square, but it is the sum of two squares.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_%28algebra%29#Examples

Comment: Hi Will. Are there an order in your field? I'd love to know it.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez, that example is not an ordered field. $-1$ is not a square but the field is still not ordered.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez "Every ordered field is a formally real field" from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field  then  definition "−1 is not a sum of squares in F." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field#Alternative_Definitions