# Diagonalizing quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms

I know how to diagonalize a given quadratic form using the *Gaussian method*. Though, I once read somewhere that there's another method which uses an augmented matrix, but I didn't go into details.

I would like to know about this method, perhaps by a simple example.

Say: $q: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, $q(x,y) = xy - y^2$.

How would I use that method to diagonalize $q$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$ xy - y^2 = \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^2 -  \left( \frac{x}{2} - y \right)^2  $$

see [Transforming quadratic forms, how is this theorem called?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240923/transforming-quadratic-forms-how-is-this-theorem-called/1240957#1240957)