# What is the difference between using $PAP^{-1}$ and $PAP^{T}$ to diagonalize a matrix?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, symmetry

What is the difference between using $PAP^{-1}$ and $PAP^{T}$ to diagonalize a matrix?

Can both methods be used to diagonalize a diagonalizable matrix $A$?

Also does $A$ been symmetric or not effect which method to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the following: When you use the formula $$P A P^{-1}$$ is because you regard the matrix $A$ as the matrix of a linear map $f$. Then the above formula tell you how the matrix $f$ change when you change the coordinates i.e. the basis. Instead the formula $$P A P^{\top} $$
is used when you regard $A$ as the matrix of a quadratic form $q$. Then the above formula tell you how change the matrix of $q$ when you change the coordinates i.e. the basis.

So in order to perform a diagonalization you have to be aware if $A$ is the matrix of either a linear map or of a quadratic form. In the special that $P^{\top} = P^{-1}$ i.e. when $P$ is orthogonal both formulae agree. This happens in the traditional method of diagonalization of a symmetric matrix by means of it eigenvectors. But in order to diagonalize a quadratic form it is not necessary to use an orthogonal matrix $P$. Such diagonalization can be done by the traditional method of completing the square:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: So, if $A$ is symmetric then I can use both methods, however if $A$ is not symmetric then I can only use $PAP^{−1}$ only, is that right?

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is not symmetric then $A$ is not the matrix of a quadratic form and you must use the formula $P A P^{-1}$ to change coordinates.

Comment: @Anonymous One thing, even if $A$ is symmetric, that doesn't mean that $P$ MUST be orthognal if $PAP^{^-1}$ is diagonal. It means that there exists a $P$ that satisfies that condition.

Comment: Indeed, this is clearly seen by taking $A$ as the identity matrix...

Answer (score 5):

You always use $PAP^{-1}$ to diagonalize a matrix, since this process (multiplying by $P$ on one side and $P^{-1}$ on the other) is effectively changing the basis of your matrix, and so is not changing many of the fundamental properties.

If $P^{-1} = P^T$ then $P$ is called an orthogonal matrix, and $PAP^{-1}$ is the same thing as $PAP^T$. A matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable (diagonalizable by an orthogonal matrix) if and only if it is symmetric.

Answer (score 4):

When the original matrix is symmetric, and using $P^T A P,$ people do not seem to be aware of the extremely easy Hermite reduction, see [Transforming quadratic forms, how is this theorem called?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240923/transforming-quadratic-forms-how-is-this-theorem-called/1240957#1240957)

Hermite reduction is just repeatedly completing the square, I did  an easy one yesterday,

$$ xy - y^2 = \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^2 -  \left( \frac{x}{2} - y \right)^2  $$

at [Diagonalizing quadratic forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323313/diagonalizing-quadratic-forms)

Let me work up an unpleasant ternary with all bad eigenvalues in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis , which just means three irrational eigenvalues for an integer matrix...I'll Be Back.

Alright, here is a "regular" ternary form with integer matrix,
$$ 3 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 5 z^2 - 4 yz + 2 zx + 2 xy,  $$
symmetric matrix

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & -2 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The characteristic polynomial is irreducible, $\lambda^3 - 11 \lambda^2 + 33 \lambda - 21,$ with approximate roots $0.867, 3.859, 6.273.$

Alright, Hermite assumes (here) that we are expecting rational numbers all around: $f(x,y,z) = 3 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 5 z^2 - 4 yz + 2 zx + 2 xy.  $ We begin with $3 (x + a y + b z)^2$ to wipe out the top row and left column of the matrix; here, 
$$ 3 \left(x + \frac{y}{3}  + \frac{z}{3}   \right)^2 = 3 \left( x^2 + \frac{y^2}{9} + \frac{z^2}{9}   + \frac{2yz}{9}  + \frac{2zx}{3}  + \frac{2xy}{3} \right) ,  $$
$$ 3 \left(x + \frac{y}{3}  + \frac{z}{3}   \right)^2 = 3  x^2 + \frac{y^2}{3} + \frac{z^2}{3}   + \frac{2yz}{3}  + 2zx + 2xy.   $$

Progress so far:
$$ f(x,y,z) - 3 \left(x + \frac{y}{3}  + \frac{z}{3}   \right)^2 =  \frac{8y^2}{3} + \frac{14 z^2}{3}   + \frac{-14yz}{3}   $$

Next,
$$ \frac{8}{3} \left( y - \frac{7z}{8} \right)^2 =  \frac{8}{3} y^2 -  \frac{14}{3}y z +  \frac{49}{24} z^2, $$
so
$$ f(x,y,z) - 3 \left(x + \frac{y}{3}  + \frac{z}{3}   \right)^2 - \frac{8}{3} \left( y - \frac{7z}{8} \right)^2 =  \frac{21z^2}{8}  $$
and
$$ f(x,y,z) = 3 \left(x + \frac{y}{3}  + \frac{z}{3}   \right)^2 + \frac{8}{3} \left( y - \frac{7z}{8} \right)^2 +  \frac{21}{8} z^2  $$

The direction I just finished, expressed in matrices, says
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1/3 & 1 & 0 \\
1/3 & -7/8 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 8/3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 21/8
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & 1 & -7/8 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & -2 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The way I did it, which may appear clumsy, makes my matrix $P$ upper triangular with all $1$'s on the diagonal, so inverting is quick:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/3 & 1 & 0 \\
-5/8 & 7/8 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & -2 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -1/3 & -5/8 \\
0 & 1 & 7/8 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 8/3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 21/8
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a matrix $A$ as either a linear operator ($x \mapsto Ax$) or a bilinear form ($x,y \mapsto <x,Ay>$). Diagonalizing it using $PAP^{-1}$ diagonalizes the linear operator $A$, i.e. changes the basis of the vector space to one in which the linear operator is diagonal, whereas diagonalizing it using $PAP^{T}$ diagonalizes the bilinear form, i.e. changes the basis of the vector space to one in which the bilinear form is diagonal.